# Strange behaviour with WFFM form submissions (?wffm.FormItemId in url)

Tags: wffm

On my local Environment and Staging Environment we have a problem where WFFM is appending the following querystring format to the urls after a form is submitted:

> ?wffm.FormItemId=79961446-e442-4b54-aee7-c6288041e852&wffm.Id=f09e1638-3610-42f7-9008-4ba91547b053

It wasn't doing this previously but I re-installed the WFFM Module and since then it has been happening.

It doesn't do this in our dev environment so it's a bit odd as the database used is the same as that used locally where it does append the querystring to the url. This suggests some file differences or config differences but I can't see anything obvious.

**Other info:**

- Sitecore 8.1 Update 2
- WFFM 8.1 rev. 160304 (Update-2)

Comment: do you have any redirects ?

Comment: Yeah we do have the url redirects module installed. I was wondering if that could be interfering with things...

Comment: can you disabled redirect and try again. Can you verify if you have js errors on submit  ?

Comment: I've disabled the redirects folder for the specific Site my form is in on my local machine and also commented out the contents of Hi.UrlRewrite.config so hopefully that should stop it running but it's still doing this. I don't get any javascript errors from what I can see.

Comment: If a success page is setup then the form submits to it fine but sends the odd querystring above. This isn't too much of an issue since the message and styling remains, but there are forms with just a success message and in these cases it submits to: /form/Index?wffm.FormItemId=daa68e17-ae75-407f-81a5-2a337619cf8f&wffm.Id=18fef29e-c5af-466b-b606-4fcf3058e17a and the screen is all white with a thank you message.

Comment: Just did a diff on the files on dev vs staging and can't see anything that would affect this either. I'm really stumped with this one...

Comment: @AdamSeabridge I have seen a similar problem but not found the solution. Check that you have the exact same JavaScript in place in both environments. This behaviour seems like something is breaking the unobtrusive ajax JS which handles the form submit.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, it does indeed seem to be an issue with some of the Js that ships with WFFM not being included due to our own jQuery version  and Js being included instead. What is strange though is that this worked fine on our dev environment and the code is exactly the same there. I have resolved it for now by re-including the WFFM Js we removed but this definitely requires more investigation to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: please open a ticket to Sitecore Support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being to do with the missing WFFM Javascript as mentioned by Matthew.

We'd removed some of this as it was causing problems with our own css and js. Oddly this was still working previously but then stopped working.

So to fix this ensure you have the following in your WFFM \Views\Form\Index.cshtml file and these exist in the /libs folder:

```
  var scripts = new List<string>
  {
    "libs/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js",
    "libs/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.3.min.js",
    "libs/jquery/jquery.validate.min.js",
    "libs/jquery/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
    "libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js",
    "wffm.min.js",
    "main.min.js"    
  };
```

These seem to be required in order to set the form post url correctly and avoid the issue with the ?wffm.FormItemId param being added to the url.